# Rdlc Report in dotnet

Tags: rdlc

I am generating rdlc report in dotnet2.0 C#. My doubt is I want to freeze the Table header (like Excel freeze) in the rdlc report. Since my table data is more, I need this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set  your fixheader property true

for this `Select Table > property > fixheader = true`

Second way open your rdlc file in xml edition

put the fix header as show below in your header tags

```
<header>
  <FixedHeader>true</FixedHeader>
</Header>
```

Comment: my table control is kept inside list , so even though i set fix header = true it is showing following error ,

" This is not allowed on data regions inside other data regions "

how to avoid this error...

please aaists me.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is old, it still came up in Google search when I was looking for a similar issue. So I'm posting this here just in case...

In SSRS 2008 the option to freeze a row or a column is FixedData = true. See this article for details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955822

Also, if your ReportViewer control is allowed to stretch to the entire HTML page, it will likely set the height of the internal table to include all rows in the dataset (or for however may rows fit on "ReportViewer page"). In that case the scroll bar is enabled for the entire page, and the report cannot keep top rows frozen. Instead place the ReportViewer control inside some viewing container and add a script to adjust width and height on window resizing.